# CSS Classes are not working in the HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, datatable

I have generated a table from my database in my Wordpress site.

You can [locate it here](https://sgquizdaily.com/all-results/)

I have added **some classes** to format the table with some conditions by **Javascript**, but it's not getting formatted.

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
         echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center' >" . $row->Time . "</td><td style='text-align: center' >" . $row->Score . "</td><td>" . $row->Name . "</td><td>" . $row->Place . "</td><td>" . $row->District . "</td><td>" . $row->Status . "</td></tr>" ;
            }
        
echo "</table></div>" ;
        
echo "<script>
var winnerName = '$winnerName'; highScore = '$highScore' ;

const table = document.getElementById('my-table');

const rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  const row = rows[i];
  const cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  
  if (cells[2] === winnerName) {
    row.classList.add('winner');
  } else if (parseInt(cells[1]) >= highScore ) {
    row.classList.add('high-score');
  }
}
</script> " ;
```

here are the CSS Classes.

```
.winner {
background-color : #acdf21;
color : white;
}

.high-score {
background-color : blue;
}
```

What went wrong, or what is preventing table formatting ..?

Please help

Comment: Try logging `cells[2]` so see if your `winnerName` matches. Please try to include a [mre]. Hard to help without being able to run it.

Comment: This does not look like vanilla JS to me. Looks like a mixed in PHP and/or Java to me

Comment: You try to compare a `td` object to a string in the JS code. Replace `cells[2]` with `cells[2].textContent` (`cells[1]` respectively).

Comment: @philipphutterer I added ```textContent```. Now I'm getting the below error in the console.

```(index):550 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
    at (index):550:16
(anonymous) @ (index):550```

Comment: Yes, because your first row does not have any `td` tags inside. Either put your `th` in `thead` and query the `tbody` before, or start the loop with `i=1` or make sure that `cells[...]` is not undefined in any other way.

Comment: Thank you @philipphutterer changed to start loop at second ```tr``` i.e. ```i=1```. 

it's now working but only ```.high-score``` class is applying, but not ```winner``` class.
how to get that one too?

Comment: The `winnerName` is currently not present in the list.

Comment: One last question, why do you want to format using JS when you could actually already format in PHP? It would be much simpler to perform the comparisons in the PHP for loop and add the desired classes also there.

Comment: thanks @philipphutterer the ```winnerName``` is there, but it's not getting formatted.

anyway thanks for your time. I will try directly in PHP

Comment: ```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $winnerClass = ($row->Name == $winnerName) ? 'winner' : '';
    $highScoreClass = ($row->Score >= $highScore) ? 'high-score' : '';
    echo "<tr class='$winnerClass $highScoreClass'><td style='text-align: center'>" . $row->Time . "</td><td style='text-align: center'>" . $row->Score . "</td><td>" . $row->Name . "</td><td>" . $row->Place . "</td><td>" . $row->District . "</td><td>" . $row->Status . "</td></tr>";
}```

Comment: Oh, actually I am now seeing that your `winner` CSS class contains a `display: none`.

Comment: thank you so much @philipphutterer since 30 minutes. i'm so confusing why it was missing. thank you . Pls paste this as your answer. I will mark it.